# UIStackView - why is the stack positioned one on top of the other?

Tags: swift

I am trying to get a group of buttons arranged within a stack view.  However, when i use a for-each loop to do this, the buttons end up being positioned one on top of the other?

```
 var stackView: UIStackView = {
    let sView = UIStackView()
    sView.axis = .vertical
    sView.distribution = .fill
    sView.alignment = .center
    return sView
}()

var optionTitles = ["Sign in", "sign out"]

for title in optionTitles{
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = optionColour.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
        allButtons.append(btn)
        stackView.addSubview(btn)
    }

    // Auto layout constraints
    for button in allButtons{
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: optionHeight).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    view.addSubview(stackView)
    stackTopConstraint = stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
    stackBottomConstraint = stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)

    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    stackTopConstraint!.isActive = true
    stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

[image]

Comment: You need to use stackView.addArrangedSubview instead of stackView.addSubview

Comment: update your stack view after viewDidLayoutSubviews, or just call view.layoutIfNeeded()

Answer (score 0):

2 things

1- You need to remove this

```
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

2- Replace

```
stackView.addSubview(btn)
```

with

```
stackView.addArrangedSubview(btn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
stackTopConstraint = stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
stackBottomConstraint = stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
```

You probably meant `view.bottomAnchor` in the second line. Surely you don't want to constraint the *bottom* of the stack view to the *top* of your view.